# Required checkbox isn't working with civem.js if user clicked submit before checking

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am using civem.js to customise my HTML form elements error messages and it's all working fine.

If the user accidentally clicked on submit before ticking the required checkbox, the will be promoted with the assigned error, message which is fine.

However, if the user goes back and checked it, the form will still not submit, asking them to check the box. It's like it wont kick the checkbox out of required mode on-click.

Here is a link; http://jsfiddle.net/BqUNS/, please click submit before ticking the checkbox.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="js/civem-0.0.6.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="First name" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Please enter your first name"> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="checked" value="checked" required data-errormessage="Please check"> <br>
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that civem.js doesn't support inputs of type checkbox. The author mentions, that he added support for radio-buttons shortly, but there is no handling for checkboxes in the  [sourcecode](https://github.com/javanto/civem.js/blob/master/src/civem.js)

Though the checkbox is recognized from the script (because it is "looking" for input-tags), there is no logic to react on change-events. Hence it doesn't recognize if the checkbox's state has changed